# remove previous controller from navigation array

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Hello In my app I am moving to all controllers randmonly at a point form 5th or 6th controller i move to first controller but when i back i move to 5th or 6th controoller, i want that when i move to again first controller i want to remove all previous controller , when i back should happen nothing

for example when i move to 5th 6th then 1st 
A -> B -> C -> D - > A

but i want this 
A > B > C > D > A (on the A point remove all previous record )

i am moving like this

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        NavigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: animated)
```

Comment: bro but i want to push becuase want to refresh whole controller due to localization

Comment: bro give me code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)`.

Example:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("navigationController?.viewControllers.count = \(navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? -1)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("ViewController1 deinit")
    }

    @IBAction func pushButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let vcIdentifier = "SecondVC"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        print("ViewController2 deinit")
    }

    @IBAction func push2ButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let vcIdentifier = "ThirdVC"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        print("ViewController3 deinit")
    }

    @IBAction func push3ButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let vcIdentifier = "FirstVC"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
        //this is what you want
        navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
    }
}
```

print output:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.count = 1
navigationController?.viewControllers.count = 1
ViewController1 deinit
ViewController2 deinit
ViewController3 deinit
```